# How to make elements disappear based on toggle switch setting

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a Slideout Menu control that looks something like this

[image]

There is a toggle switch on top which is currently switched off(i.e basic mode) and i want the elements to not be visible when the toggle is in basic mode, except for the Definition label and the dropdown next to it. When the switch is turned on (i.e Advanced mode) the menu should look like this (the image).
The html for the toggle switch is

```
<label class="switch">
      <input type="checkbox">
      <span class="slider round"></span>
      </label>
```

The UI controls are not properly aligned as I am learning to write HTML/CSS on the go.

This is one of the controls that should not be available in the screen when the toggle switch is in basic mode

```
<div class="dropdowns-container">
      <label kmdFormLabel>Rounding Mode</label>
      <kmd-dropdown
      [(ngModel)]="roundMode"
      [options]="allRoundModes"
      [disable]="!editable"
      size="medium"
      [externalLabel]="true"
      inlineLabel="Select Rounding Mode"
      (onChange)="roundModeChange($event)">
      </kmd-dropdown>
    </div>
```

How can this be done, is there any specific control or Angular setting that i could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's only create a variable, e.g. "advancedShow", and enclosed all the inputs in a ng-container with an "if"

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="advancedShow">
    <span class="slider round"></span>
</label> 
    ...here your inputs always visible..
<ng-container *ngIf="advancedShow">
    ...here yours inputs only sisible if slider is true...
</ng-container>
```